# Cannot find activate file in Python venv in Linux

Tags: python, python-venv

**I am trying to install venv but getting this error:**

> name@malikov:~/Desktop/informtech$ python3 -m venv venv
> Error: Command '['/home/name/Desktop/informtech/venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

**venv folder created but there is no activate file to activate venv**
[image]

What should I do. Is there any solution. All problems started after upgrading python version from 3.8 to 3.10**strong text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing `venv` for `python3.10` via command:

`sudo apt install python3.10-venv`